# IE9 CSS universal selector takes precedence over direct selector with important

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

So I have a universal selector in my CSS file to change a few things like font-family and color, as those rules can be applied to just about anything with one or two exceptions:

```
*
{
    font-family: "Roboto", Sans, Arial, serif;
    color: white;

    outline:none;
}
```

One of those cases turns out to be select boxes, which are somewhat configurable in IE.

The white text color conflicts with the natural white background of the select box, so I added the following rule *after* the universal selector:

```
div#cart div.donate p select
{
    color: black !important;
}
```

But IE 9 still uses the universal rule over the targeted rule. Why?

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6TBxs/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Why are you using the universal selector? Use something like body { color: white} and let the cascade take care of the rest.

Comment: !important is a trap. The rest of us use CSS specificity.

Comment: @sdsanders Good point. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @Diodeus I only used important there because the plain color:black rule was not working. I normally never use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that the universal rule has higher specificity, it's that `select` is not going to style the text color in IE9.

From your JSFiddle, `#gift-sel option` will style that text in IE9, as IE9 is relying on `option` instead of `select` to style the color.